# How to execute a python file from another python file which is in different directory

Tags: python

I have a python file in different directory and I don't want to change the directory of the file so how can I execute another python file from my first python file

Comment: Might want to check this: [How to import a module given the full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can spawn a new process using os.system command and use it like that.

```
import os

os.system('python absolute/path/to/file.py')
```